# How to implement maxlen in my code

Tags: python-3.x

I just started programming a few months ago and I am not sure what to do on my task. I need to modify the ArrayStack implementation so that the stack’s capacity is limited
to maxlen elements, where maxlen is an optional parameter to the constructor (that defaults to
None). If push is called when the stack is at full capacity, throw a Full exception (defined similarly to
Empty).

```
class Empty(Exception):
pass

class ArrayStack:
"""LIFO Stack implementation using a Python list as underlying storage."""


  def __init__(self):
"""Create an empty stack."""
self._data = []                       # nonpublic list instance

   def __len__(self):
"""Return the number of elements in the stack."""
return len(self._data)

   def is_empty(self):
"""Return True if the stack is empty."""
return len(self._data) == 0

  def push(self, e):
"""Add element e to the top of the stack."""
self._data.append(e)                  # new item stored at end of list

 def top(self):
 """Return (but do not remove) the element at the top of the stack.

Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty.
"""
if self.is_empty():
  raise Empty('Stack is empty')
return self._data[-1]                 # the last item in the list

def pop(self):
"""Remove and return the element from the top of the stack (i.e., LIFO).

Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty.
"""
if self.is_empty():
  raise Empty('Stack is empty')
return self._data.pop()               # remove last item from list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the parameter to the constructor and to the push method

```
class Empty(Exception):
    pass

class ArrayStack:
"""LIFO Stack implementation using a Python list as underlying storage."""


    def __init__(self, maxlen=None):
        """Create an empty stack."""
        self._data = []                      # nonpublic list instance
        self.maxlen=maxlen

    def __len__(self):
        """Return the number of elements in the stack."""
        return len(self._data)

    def is_empty(self):
        """Return True if the stack is empty."""
        return len(self._data) == 0

    def push(self, e):
        """Add element e to the top of the stack."""
        if len(self._data) == self.maxlen:
            raise Exception # Whatever exception you want
        self._data.append(e)                  # new item stored at end of list

    def top(self):
        """Return (but do not remove) the element at the top of the stack.

           Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty.
        """
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Empty('Stack is empty')
        return self._data[-1]                 # the last item in the list

    def pop(self):
        """Remove and return the element from the top of the stack (i.e., LIFO).
           Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty.
        """
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Empty('Stack is empty')
        return self._data.pop()               # remove last item from list
```